# how can i connect mysql to python

Tags: mysql, python-3.7

I have the following code:

```
import mysql.connector
conn=mysql.connector(user="B13046",password="Likhi46",host="localhost")
```

But I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

How can i resolve the traceback ?

Comment: try importing mysql but not mysql.connector

Answer (score 0):

You should use `mysql.connector.connect`:

```
import mysql.connector
conn=mysql.connector.connect(user="B13046",password="Likhi46",host="localhost")
```

See [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html) for more features